# Google Play tablet optimization tips - how to resolve issues?

Tags: android, google-play

When listing an app in Google Play the optimization tips tells me 3 issues:

```
WHAT YOU SHOULD DO  WHY WE ARE PROPOSING THIS   
Design your app for tablets
Your APK needs to meet the following criteria:
1) Target and minimum Android versions support tablets (check targetSdkVersion and     minSdkVersion). Learn more
2) Supports common tablet screen sizes (LARGE and XLARGE). Learn more
3) Includes custom drawables and assets for common tablet screen densities. Learn more
```

Here is my manifest concerning the first 2 issues:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                 android:normalScreens="true"
                 android:largeScreens="true"
                 android:xlargeScreens="true"
                 android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480" />
```

The "Learn more" link sends me off to the instructions.  The app works on phones but I'm targeting tablets so I want Google play to know it is tablet compatible.  What am I doing wrong here?  I'm still in the "alpha/ready-to-publish" phase so I cant tell if it really will get listed in the tablet section yet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem too - I think the Optimization Tips only refer to the "Production" APK, not an alpha/beta one, so if you don't have a production APK, it gives all these warnings. When I transferred the APK to production, the warnings went away. (Beware, you can't move an APK back from Production to Alpha/Beta, or otherwise remove it, so unfortunately this isn't useful as an easy way to check.)

Comment: I updated the SDK and added the new xxhdpi drawables. Google support even got back to me and said I was tablet compatible too but the optimization tips are still warning me.  I think you are correct but I'm not quite ready to move to production yet to test it. I will come back and confirm this answer as soon as I promote it to production. Thanks

Comment: Published today and now it says:  "You are doing pretty well
We do not have any optimization tips for you right now."